# Style tag_list class from Acts as Taggable On

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, acts-as-taggable-on, acts-as-taggable

I'm undoubtedly missing something obvious, but how should I style the output of individual tags produced by `<%= user.tag_list %>`?

`<%= user.tag_list, :class => 'tags' %>` doesn't work...

Note, I want to style the individual results, not the whole block.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<% user.tag_list.each do |tag| %>
  <span class="tags"><%= tag %></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I went with in the end :-)